# upload speed control from IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7

If I am using IIS 7.0 + Server 2008/Vista Enterprise, any ways from IIS 7.0 side to control the upload speed? For example, max upload speed at 1M bytes/second?

Any configuration based easy solution is great! And any programming based solution is also appreciated. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any controls within IIS to handle this.  A customer ISAPI handler would probably be able to do so, but that would be a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, do you know whether there are any open source implementation for such ISAPI control available? I may need to have some customization.

Comment: No, I don't sorry.  Check SourceForge and CodePlex and see what you can find.

Comment: For non-open source ones as you suggested, what products do you mean? Could you recommend some please? :-)

Comment: I don't know of any commercial products either.  I know that one company I worked for did this sort of this for one of our web clusters.  You might want to check over on stack overflow and see if anyone has any code that can help out.

Comment: What is the commercial product you are working on? Do you recommend me to use it? :-)

Comment: This wasn't a product for sale.  It was part of our system.